# Composite Key with a column that auto increments and reset when foreign key value changes

Tags: database-design, table

I am trying to implement a ticket system, the numbers generated would be sequential.

4000, 4001, 4002, 4003

My idea was to have a table that relates to current raffle, and the ticket_no column is an auto increment column that resets when the foreign key changes.

The composite keys are `raf_id` and `ticket_no` since the ticket no should not exist multiple times in same raffle

Is this possible?

```
|------------|-----------|---------|
| raf_id     | ticket_no | user_id |
|------------|-----------|---------|
| 1          | 4000      | 1       |
| 1          | 4001      | 1       |
| 1          | 4002      | 2       |
| 1          | 4003      | 3       |
| 2          | 4000      | 4       |
| 2          | 4001      | 4       |
| 2          | 4002      | 5       |
| 2          | 4003      | 1       |
|------------|-----------|---------|
```

Answer (score 0):

## Automatic?

Unknown.  Most likely, not. (as in: no out-of-the-box database features)

## Manual?

Yes.

You need to keep track of "last number used" in a table. eg

```sql
create table raf (
  raf_id        int, -- identity/autoincrement
  last_number   int default 4000 not null,
  constraint raf_pk primary key (raf_id)
);
```

From there, your process needs to go like this:

1. grab a lock for `RAF_ID`
2. "calculate" the next number.
3. Update the `RAF` table.
4. Use that value in the other table
5. `COMMIT` the data
6. Release the lock.

Depending on your RDBMS, some steps can be combined into a single step.  The HOWTO do these things (eg Best practice for "grab a lock") can also be RDBMS dependent.

## Notes

The "grab a lock" step will serialize your code.  This is bad for databases.  This requirement/process will limit how fast you can add new rows.  I suggest you look at alternative methods (eg a `VIEW` that uses `RANK()` ).

Can this be implemented in a `TRIGGER`?  Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If Ticket.ID is auto-incrementing, then why not calculate "ticket number" as (Ticket.ID - MIN(Ticket.ID) over (PARTITION BY Ticket.Raf_ID)) + 1? If you ever have multiple raffles issuing tickets simultaneously, this could lead to non-sequential ticket number. But you'll never get multiples, and it doesn't require setting up complex write logic.